# Pixel values cannot be read for smaller image but can read for larger image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

i am using the following code for reading an image and displaying pixel values on screen

```
#include<iostream>

#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv; 


int main()
{

Mat img = imread("C:\\cat.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //open and read the image

      if (img.empty())
     {
          cout << "Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          return -1;
     }

      cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY); //change the color image to grayscale image

 int rows = img.rows;
 int cols =img.cols;

 cv::Size s = img.size();
rows = s.height;
cols = s.width;

// this loop is to get all the pixel values
uchar val;
for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)
{
for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
{
val = img.at<uchar>(r,c);
cout << (int)val <<"  ";
}
cout<<endl;
}
// to get a single value of pixelu need a variable 
val = img.at<uchar>(40,50);

    cout << (int)val << endl;

 imshow("showImg",img);
     cvWaitKey(0);

    return 1;


      waitKey(0); //wait for key press

      destroyAllWindows(); //destroy all open windows
return 0;
}
```

//    it works fine for larger image but when i use 8x8 .jpg or .tiff image it displays //the image instead of pixel values and gives an error

//"Unhandled exception at 0x75c7c41f (KernelBase.dll) in opencvconfig.exe: Microsoft C++ //exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0030f354.."

//this error is displayed can any 1 please help , i want help as soon as posssible

Comment: Possible caused by `img.at<uchar>(40,50)` accessing somewhere in the boondocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete these lines

```
// to get a single value of pixelu need a variable 
val = img.at<uchar>(40,50);

cout << (int)val << endl;
```

(40,50) is not a valid location, and accessing it is the most probable cause of the exception